# Java Servlet not running

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I am using netbeans and Glassfish but my servlet does not seem to run. I followed exactly the same thing as this tutorial 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_zW27Y2boCo

but when I try to run the servlet, it gives me an error message like

```
HTTP Status 404 - Not Found

type Status report

messageNot Found

descriptionThe requested resource is not available.
```

This is my web.xml file:

```
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
     version="3.1">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>StudentServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.sushan.controller.StudentServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>StudentServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/StudentServlet</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>studentInfo.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

</web-app>
```

Normally when I try to run the servlet on its own, it should open and even when doing it through the jsp, it gives an error like this

```
HTTP Status 500 - Internal Server Error

type Exception report

messageInternal Server Error

descriptionThe server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

javax.ejb.EJBException: Transaction aborted
note The full stack traces of the exception and its root causes are available in the GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 4.1 logs.
```

Anyone know what is going on?

Comment: What is the url that is giving you 404?

Comment: What part exactly of *"note The full stack traces of the exception and its root causes are available in the GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 4.1 logs.
"* didn't you understand?

Comment: @VHS http://localhost:8080/CRUDWebApplication/StudentServlet is giving me that error

Comment: @BalusC I couldn't find the logs it's telling me to go to sorry :/

Comment: `javax.ejb.EJBException` - apparently  there is something wrong in your EJB method.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

*HTTP Status 500* means that the server encountered an unexpected condition which prevented it from fulfilling the request. You probably have mistake with  request/response. Check your code and try again.